# How do I assign selected file to filepathfield

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Currently I have a university model which has a logo field.

I want the user to be able to choose a picture among existing ones in specific directory when they are editing university details. Image path will be saved in logo field.

### In University

```
class University(models.Model):
    logo = models.FilePathField()
```

When I create a model form (UniversityForm) based on the university model, the filepathfield get displayed as select box by default. And I noticed if I type code below

### in UniversityForm

```
class UniversityForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UniversityForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['logo'] = forms.FilePathField(path=UNIVERSITY_LOGOS_DIR, match=".*\.(png|jpg)$", recursive=False)
```

The selected box will be populated with image names under logos directory every time I refresh the page and I can select an image for that university.

But problem comes when I want to display the selected image along the select box, it seems that the filepathfield saves absolute path of images and I have no way to retrieve selected image from filepathfield.

I tried [Django Templates - how do I output the relative path of file when using a FilePathField recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242127/django-templates-how-do-i-output-the-relative-path-of-file-when-using-a-filepa), and I now can retrive file name and display it using code below

### in UniversityForm

```
 class UniversityForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UniversityForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['logo'] = forms.FilePathField(path=UNIVERSITY_LOGOS_DIR, match=".*\.(png|jpg)$", recursive=False)

    def university_logo_url(self):
        return self.fields['logo'].choices[0][1]
```

### in template

```
    {% if field.label == 'Logo' %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
            <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}university_logos/{{ form.university_logo_url }}" alt="university_logo"/>
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
```

But after all I still couldn't figure out a way to get the selected image in filepathfield, and I cannot refresh the image when the selection changes. Thus I couldn't save the path selected image, every time the server restarts previous selections 
will gone.

What's the proper way to meet my requirement in django?
Maybe create another widget to select from and save the result in filepathfield?

FYI I used https://stackoverflow.com/a/1235542/2601579 to get the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have 2 options:

1. Employ a custom widget and a little bit of jQuery magic to rewrite the filepathfield's full path into it's url representation every time you change the dropdown box.
2. Create a custom field that combines the recursive search behavior of FilePathField with the StorageEngine backend of FileField.

1 is going to be way easier to do as a 1-off. 2 is going to take more effort, but may pay off if you need this functionality in multiple places